# How to access Raspberry Pi webapp on remote devices, with RasPi as accesspoint

Tags: raspbian, web-server, networkmanager

I'm working on a remote car to use outdoors. I'm controlling motors with relays using a flask webapp running at localhost. I can access the webapp when raspi is on my home network, by loading it's ip:port. Now I want raspi to work as a wireless access point or something so that I can connect to it's network and load the webapp in mobile browser. Can you please explain how can I go about doing that?
So basically I want raspi to act as a server and any device with access can load the page in webbrwoser.

Comment: Look here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way). You may follow the section "*Setting up a stand alone access point.*"